Trying to include response body to my response with reqwest and actix_web without consuming the original resp
It's my understanding that unwrap from Result<Response, Error> type results in it consuming the original.
I cannot have that, so I need to be able to only borrow it for my fetching of response body. I cannot figure out the proper way access the response body. I tried multiple ways like with match, but coming from not so type strict languages, I'm really lost. I was also thinking that properly something like:
let resp = CLIENT.execute(request).await;
let bytes = resp.unwrap().bytes().await?;

Could work, but that also consumes the first resp, which is needed later in the code.
use actix_web::http::{Method, StatusCode};
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpResponseBuilder, HttpServer};
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use qstring::QString;
use regex::Regex;
use reqwest::{Body, Client, Request, Url};
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::ErrorKind;
use std::{env, io, fmt};


static CLIENT: Lazy<Client> = Lazy::new(|| {
    let builder = Client::builder()
        .user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0");

    let proxy = if let Ok(proxy) = env::var("PROXY") {
        Some(reqwest::Proxy::all(proxy).unwrap())
    } else {
        None
    };

    let builder = if let Some(proxy) = proxy {
        // proxy basic auth
        if let Ok(proxy_auth_user) = env::var("PROXY_USER") {
            let proxy_auth_pass = env::var("PROXY_PASS").unwrap_or_default();
            builder.proxy(proxy.basic_auth(&proxy_auth_user, &proxy_auth_pass))
        } else {
            builder.proxy(proxy)
        }
    } else {
        builder
    };

    if get_env_bool("IPV4_ONLY") {
        builder
            .local_address(Some("0.0.0.0".parse().unwrap()))
            .build()
            .unwrap()
    } else {
        builder.build().unwrap()
    }
});



async fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> Result<HttpResponse, Box<dyn Error>> {

   if req.method() == Method::OPTIONS {
        let mut response = HttpResponse::Ok();
        add_headers(&mut response);
        return Ok(response.finish());
   } else if req.method() != Method::GET && req.method() != Method::HEAD {
        let mut response = HttpResponse::MethodNotAllowed();
        add_headers(&mut response);
        return Ok(response.finish());
   }

<snip>

let resp = CLIENT.execute(request).await;
let resp_clone = resp.clone() // This seems impossible due to the Reqwest not implementing clone, but what I'm interested in are the response status and body that I want to reply with as this is a proxy and currently it only returns the status when it encounters an error eg 403, but I want the body to be returned too.
let resp_body = resp_clone?.text().await.unwrap_or_else(|_| String::from("Failed to read response body"));

if let Err(err) = resp_clone.unwrap().error_for_status() {
   eprintLn!("Error from upstream server: {:?}, Response body: {:?}", err, resp_body);
   return Err(err.into());
}

let resp = resp?;

let mut response = HttpResponse::build(resp.status());

<snip>


Since reading the body consumes Response, you need to extract the information you need beforehand, whether it's headers, status, or an IO error. Reqwest: read body text and return reqwest::Error

The entire problem though is that I cannot do anything to the Response that will consume it? Otherwise rest of it doesn't really work?

you can do exactly one thing that consumes it, and you must do it last.

Which this cannot be the last thing.. To my understanding anyway as there's a lot more code after that.
